# How to prerender page from Frontend?

Tags: angularjs, metadata, ngroute, prerender

I have a page at the moment with different kinds of "items" with an unique URL for each item.

```
www.example.com/mysite/items/banana-split/images
www.example.com/mysite/items/apple-pie/images
```

I'm using *AngularJS* with *ngRoute* and *ngMeta* + *JS* + *HTML5* + *CSS* only and I host my site at `one.com`.

It works fine at the moment and when I click on an item everything works fine and the title is changed and I try to change the `metaData` also.
Though when I link my products to Whatsapp or Facebook or similar services it only displays:

```
{{ngMeta.title}} {{ngMeta.description}}
```

I know it has to do with the prerendering of the page and it doesn't prerender my page. I've looked at prerender.io etc, but since it's using NodeJS I don't think I can host it on one.com. Maybe on AWS, but one.com is what I pay for.

Are there any way for me to fix this from .htaccess file or from the pure frontend?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/saymedia/angularjs-server

Comment: What is the source of your data for those pages/routes? Do they come from HTTP calls or are you using static data? If your data are static, there is a pretty simple workaround but if they are coming from HTTP calls then this is one of the most common problem and challenge faced by most of the Single Page Applications

Comment: @AparAdhikari My source is Google Firebase. When I init my page it pulls the data from Firebase to receive all the data that I'm going to use on my page. I don't know if Google Firebase is doing a HTTP request in behind.